# How to run ng serve without building first

Tags: angular, angular-cli

I need to BUILD my app using **`ng build --prod`** on **machine #1** and to SERVE my app using **`ng serve --prod`** on **machine #2**

**Machine #2** should NOT have the source files and has not the processing/RAM capacity to bundle them anyway.

I can't find a way to serve the already bundled files.

Any idea ?

Comment: Related question: [webpack - How to serve an Angular 2 dist folder index.html - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389539/how-to-serve-an-angular-2-dist-folder-index-html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could simply install a node Web Server on machine #2

```
npm install http-server -g
cd dist
http-server
```

At https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server you'll find more information

Comment: Yes I know a lot of other http servers out there, but my requirements are to use angular-cli the serve my files.
Furthermore, the index.html generated by ng build --prod do not include .gz bundles versions, so I guess ng serve compress them on the fly, and the result is 5 times smaller files loaded

Comment: The webserver does the gzip compression if the Client sends the right ```Accept-Enconding``` headers see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Accept-Encoding.

Why do you need to use ng?

Comment: Tried to build with ng build --prod and to serve with http-server just now. Huge difference in loaded file sizes...

Comment: Ok... I found the option "-g" of http-server :-D

Comment: Thanks a lot btw :-)