# How to serve an Angular 2 dist folder index.html

Tags: angular, webpack, webpack-dev-server

I'm using this angular 4 seed app: https://github.com/2sic/app-tutorial-angular4-hello-dnn

It uses webpack and works fine.

It only seems to serve the dev files and not the dist/ folder.

I want to ng serve the dist folder.

Not sure the command to do this or if I need to install a lite server or something.

**I run this command to create the dist folder (which works fine):**

```
g build --prod --aot --output-hashing=none
```

Now I want to run this build in the browser.

Comment: I am new to angular4, may I know what is dist, build

Comment: @SoumyaGangamwar if you want to build for an environment, which should be deployed and accessible from outside `localhost`, you can put your compiled sources into a dist (distribution) folder - which is then served by a http-server and propagated to the "outside" world. and `dist` is just a default name widely used for that purpose...

Comment: Below stack url can be helpful https://stackoverflow.com/a/53300931/7165958

Comment: @Guntram: That's exactly what I would like to do (making it accessible outside localhost). How would I specify IP and port?

Comment: `node_modules\.bin\ng serve --port 4200 --base-href /my-app/ --host 0.0.0.0` does a standard serve, and host 0000 makes the served app accessible to the network from another computer. (the ip is the ip of your computer)

Answer (score 79):

You can use http-server for doing so. First of all generate a build using the command `ng build --prod --aot --output-hashing=none`. This will create a dist folder in your directory structure.

After this, run `http-server ./dist`, which will start serving your project from dist folder.

Make sure you have installed http-server globally using

```
npm install http-server -g
```

For reference, see https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server

Comment: Thanks, been looking to test my application build. I knew I probably needed to run the build on a server but could not find info on this anywhere. This needs to be pushed higher up google ranking.

Answer (score 36):

At least for Angular apps, `angular-http-server` seems to be a nicer option.

First install it with your prefered package manager, say

```
npm install angular-http-server -g
```

or

```
yarn global add angular-http-server
```

Then execute it:

```
angular-http-server --path path/to/dist/folder
```

Look at the [repo](https://github.com/simonh1000/angular-http-server) for more information about usage.

PS: According the author, it should also work with other SPA frameworks (React, Vue and so forth).

PPS: Do **not** use `angular-http-server` for production, use this solution for testing purposes only.

Comment: Using the `angular-http-server` server solved the issue I had which I described at `https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52786539/all-requests-are-not-found-404-when-the-application-runs-on-an-external-server/52786726`

Comment: @Stephane I'm glad it helped!

Comment: How would I specify the IP address, e.g. `http://0.0.0.0`; port can be done via the `-p` flag.

Comment: Note: I wondered what the `angular-http-server` vs `http-server` rule was.  https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server says that `angular-http-server`  should not be used as a production server; only for development; whilst https://www.npmjs.com/package/http-server claims `http-server` can be used for production.  `nginx` can also be used (see https://medium.com/bb-tutorials-and-thoughts/how-to-serve-angular-application-with-nginx-and-docker-3af45be5b854)

Comment: @JohnLBevan Good point. When I posted this answer I assumed OP wanted a solution for development only - as a comment to another answer below OP says "I want to **test** the dist folder". Like you said, the procedure I describe here should **not** be used for production.

Answer (score 19):

You need a server to serve your generated build.

I am using http-server. Install http-server using:

```
npm install -g http-server
```

now go inside your dist folder and run this command

```
http-server
```

as shown here:

[image]

Check http://localhost:8080 in your browser

Answer (score 6):

A little tips

so you avoid to install globally

install in your root

```
npm i http-server
```

in your package.json

```
"scripts": {
    "pwa": "http-server ./dist"
  }
```

than

```
npm run pwa
```

Answer (score 5):

I use the VS Code extension [Live Server](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ritwickdey.LiveServer).

1. Run your `ng build` which will output the `dist/` folder with `index.html`
2. Open separate instance of VS Code onto the `dist/` folder
3. Press "Go Live" button in bottom right of VS Code status bar [image] which you will see after installing the Live Server extension.

Answer (score 4):

I serve the dist folder with the Angular CLI...

ng serve --prod=true

> When true, sets the build configuration to the production target. All builds make use of bundling and limited tree-shaking. A production build also runs limited dead code elimination.

https://angular.io/cli/serve

Comment: The --prod option will compile the files and run it from streaming and not from folder /dist

Answer (score 3):

I tried with http-server by installing it globally

```
npm install -g http-server
```

then moved to the dist/project-folder and tried with

```
http-server -o
```

output in console

```
[Fri Sep 13 2019 15:19:57 GMT+0530 (India Standard Time)] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.132
Safari/537.36"
```

Then this solution worked with all the steps same but instead of using http-server try `angular-http-server`

It worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

You don't need to install anything, Just use the following command.

```
npx lite-server --baseDir="dist/"
```

Comment: Please provide additional details in your answer. As it's currently written, it's hard to understand your solution.

Answer (score 1):

`ng serve` will work as normal, and it doesn't require a prior build. It generates files in memory, and has some additional features like auto reload.

Comment: Hi, I have ng serve working but its serving the dev files and not that dist folder. I want to test the dist folder using serve. whats the command for that?

Comment: angular-cli can't do that. You want an instant or production grade static server instead.

Comment: do you know any I could install?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16333790/node-js-quick-file-server-static-files-over-http

Comment: The question is clear, and this answer doesn't answer it. Should have been a comment.

Answer (score 1):

Install this globally (or locally)

```
npm i -g lite-server
```

Run this command (replace **project-name**)

```
lite-server --baseDir="dist/project-name"
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend [web dev server](https://modern-web.dev/docs/dev-server/overview/). I found it to be light and easy to use. It also has a nice watch option

From inside the `dist/` folder I run this command

```
% wds -p 8080 --watch   
Web Dev Server started...
```