# Angular 2 CLI - How to use /dist folder files created by angular-cli ng build

Tags: angular

I'm generating dist folder after ng build and my directory looks like

```
C:\Source\angular> ng build
```

[image]

cut and past the dist folder in another directory

```
C:\ReSource\angularbuild
```

[image]

After changing  in Index.html to

```
<base href="./ReSource/angularbuild/dist">
```

Then

```
C:\Source\angular> ng serve
```

Getting inline.bundle.js,main.bundle.js,styles.bundle.js,vendor.bundle.js,main.bundle.js 404 not found errors

How could i achieve it ?  I want to run the dist folder which is placed in angularbuild folder from `C:\Source\angular>`

Let me know the right way to do it.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

After ng build, it just needs a server to execute it, instead of ng serve you can install an http-server from your terminal `npm i -g http-server --save` then execute your project from the dist folder using the command (y) :

```
http-server ./dist
```

Or on apache for who are using Wamp or Xamp for example just copy the entire files on the dist folder inside your www folder, then restart Apache service

Answer (score 20):

Dist folder is not for ng serve

> It's a build that you can run without ng commands

```
ng build :
```

It creates the build of your project , converts all your ".ts files" and other files to the simple js files that browser can understand.

So there is no need to run `ng serve` over the dist folder ,

> just open index.html file inside dist folder and your whole project
>   will run.

Comment: If you deploy the angular4 dist directory on you webserver to /test, then you can build it as follows:

Comment: can dist folders content like main.xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx.js can be edited?

Comment: Yes you can , but you should not :) @T.Shashwat

Comment: actually I tried editing my main.XXXXXXX.js but in vain as files are compressed and will not catch up with changes you do. 
so instead I tried working on my source code and again build the project and after that I just re-named main.xxxxxxxx.js to my previous file(main.xxxxxxxxx.js) available in my shared hosting provider(Hosgator). and I can see the changes reflected in my live website.

Comment: Angular 6 here. Mine did not launch the project. I double clicked `index.html` but I get in console lots of `Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND` for favicon, my runtime and polyfills JS files, etc...

Comment: @KurtMiller may be it help you [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569668/not-able-to-execute-angular-application-locally-after-build#comment78114162_45569668)

Answer (score 3):

If you deploy the angular4 project on you webserver to sub folder DOCUMENT_ROOT/test, then you can do the build as follows:

ng build --prod --base-href "/test/".

Copy the dist/* files to DOCUMENT_ROOT/test.

Access the app through: http://myserver/test. That worked for me.

Comment: Indeed, so don't forget the `--prod` flag for production people. Thanks for sharing.

Answer (score 1):

Steps to create build is

```
> ng build --prod // can be other environment
```

To serve /dist folder created by angular-cli ng build command we can use "[serve](https://www.npmjs.com/package/serve)" 
use below command to install serve

```
> yarn global add serve
```

and run

```
serve dist/
```

You will get url and try it on any browser.

Comment: This is awesome, thanks! In my case I had to use `npx serve dist`