# Not able to execute Angular application locally after build

Tags: angular, build, rendering, angular-cli

I'm toying with the CLI tools for Angular. When I execute

> ng serve

the application comes to live and is working all great. Now, I'd like to distribute it to the wide web and attempted building it by

> ng build --verbose

which seems to have worked as I see no errors nor warnings. However, as I enter the created *dist* directory and execute FF on *index.html*, I arrive at a blank page.

Checking the source, I see that the included bundles are there but that the tag app-root that is the entry point of my Angular application isn't rendered to anything. The list of bundles included is as follows (I try to keep it as default and standard as possible):

```
<body style="padding-top: 70px;">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="inline.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="polyfills.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="styles.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="vendor.bundle.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="main.bundle.js"></script>
</body>
```

I'm assuming that all the magic required to render the stuff in *main.bundle.js* is provided in *inline.bundle.js* and/or any of the other bundles included. Is it so?

Since I see no errors in the console, serving it form the *src* directory works etc. I'm guessing I've forgotten something fairly simple that needs to be switched on or commented out or something. Googling such a vague question resulted in a bunch of useless info.

What can I do about it? How can I troubleshoot it deeper?

Comment: What does "_execute FF on index.html_" mean?

Comment: did you check on all multiple browsers ? I faced same problem on MicrosoftEdge it didn't produce any errors but in Chrome bundles not found errors use to appear.

Comment: @echonax Ahem... It means I run FF and use the path of the file *index.html* as the parameter. I also tried to type it by hand in the address field but it led to the same result. Or am I misunderstanding your question?

Comment: @k11k2 I used FF, Cr and IE. Same result.

Comment: did you try to open the html file in dist folder after build `ng build`. Is it performing fine or still blank page?

Comment: @k11k2 Sorry if I wasn't clear enough in my question. I opened the *index.html* in my *dist* directory with several browsers. I only get a blank page. The *app-root* component isn't rendered into the template that I've designed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I use this script instead of   `<base href="/">` in index.html to open file in dist directory. I'm not sure it may be the solution for you but may help.

```
<script>
    document.write('<base href="' + String(document.location).replace('index.html','') + '">')
    </script>
```

Comment: Actually, this did the trick even better than serving it from a web service. This is precisely what I was looking for. Now, my only concern is that it may fudge up things later on when I'm ready to deploy. But the question is rightly answered here.

Comment: @AndyJ Let me know after deployment. want to know does it cause any fudge or not.

Comment: As far I can tell it does not. Haven't tried with routing yet, though. Also, I see warning about violation by using `document.write()`suggesting to avoid it. Other than that, nope. Seems all right. Although a bit hacky, of course, but that wasn't a part of the question that you answered.

Comment: currently my local project contains node files,Oauth angular authentication,routing,HTTP calls, multilingual support package all works fine but didn't know about the behaviour after deployment.

Answer (score 1):

That is because you are not serving you page. You would need a simple webserver like [Nginx](http://nginx.org/en/download.html).

However if you really want this, it is possible, but without routing. You should do the following:

- Make your scriptpaths in your `index.html` relative: `<script type="text/javascript" src="./inline.bundle.js"></script>`
- Set your `base href` to the location of your dist folder:
- Use IE11 or EDGE. FF and Crome will give you security warnings.

Comment: Well, I can use *ng serve* and serve it like that too. The problem is that if I upload the files to Azure I want them to perform. And I hardly doubt MS lets me install/configure Nginx up there... Suggestions on that?

Comment: `ng serve` uses a web server, I believe it is LiteServer. When running `ng serve --oat --prod` you get some warning like: "don't use liteServer as  your production server". About you Azure thing, isn't Azure basically a webserver? Anyway there are enough questions here about Angular deployments on Azure.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think the routers can figure out how to handle a file:// url. The way Angular does the routes is somewhat disturbing. When you navigate to a route, it depends on the web server serving up the default document (index.html) and then it essentially re-writes the URL to consider anything after the base to be handled internally by the router.

In short, serve from an actual web server.

Comment: I thought so too but I tried the *index.html* at the root and I have removed all the routing. I actually only have a single component now (*app.component.ts* file) and no linking/routing what so ever. Isn't the transpiled file just a static JS that's supposed to do some magic with the DOM, then? I was going to simply upload the files to my server in Azure but I feel that it's not going to fly there neither without me executing *ng serve* (or whatever else web server might be available in Azure) and I strongly dislike the need to configure stuff up there.   :)

Comment: You might get improved results by monkeying with the <base> tag in your web page. Try setting it to blank. Still, trying to serve from the file system directly is always going to be unpredictably different than using a web server because all the modern 'easy to reason about' web idioms are actually really difficult to reason about without learning 100% of how they work at a low level.

'ng serve' always hides a bit of magic but I think the only important thing is that your Azure web server knows to use index.html as the default document.

Comment: Allright. Let's try it out and hope for the best. Thanks!