# Angular 4 cli generated project, integration with Asp.Net Core issue

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, asp.net-core, angular-cli

I am facing problem integrating angular 4 cli project into Visual Studio 2017 with Asp.Net core project.

Here are the steps that I have taken.

1. Created a angular4 project with >ng new shoppingcart
2. Inside the
       shoppingcart folder, I have created a Dot net web api project using >dotnet new webapi
3. Opened the dot new project in Visual studio 2017, and changed the
   outDir entry in .angular-cli.json to "outDir": "wwwroot".
4. Added a service namely app.service.ts and invoked the web api
   controller.
5. Ran the application from visual studio and the browser opens. It
   shows http://localhost:6353/ and error 404 is shown.

Now if I type "http://localhost:6353/values, then I get the values returned by values controller, which is understandable.

But, my problems are these:

a) It is supposed to show the index.html under src folder (by copying it to wwwroot folder), but it does not. As a result, entire typescript logic is not getting executed. 
b) the browser is supposed to show the same index .html, but it does not.

Can you help me?

Here is my

> .angular-cli.json file.

```
  {
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "project": {
  "name": "shopping-cart"
 },
 "apps": [
  {
  "root": "src",
  "outDir": "wwwroot",
  "assets": [
    "assets",
    "favicon.ico"
  ],
  "index": "index.html",
  "main": "main.ts",
  "polyfills": "polyfills.ts",
  "test": "test.ts",
  "tsconfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
  "testTsconfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
  "prefix": "app",
  "styles": [
    "styles.css"
  ],
  "scripts": [],
  "environmentSource": "environments/environment.ts",
  "environments": {
    "dev": "environments/environment.ts",
    "prod": "environments/environment.prod.ts"
  }
 }
],
  "e2e": {
  "protractor": {
  "config": "./protractor.conf.js"
  }
 },
 "lint": [
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "src/tsconfig.spec.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
},
{
  "project": "e2e/tsconfig.e2e.json",
  "exclude": "**/node_modules/**"
}
],
"test": {
 "karma": {
  "config": "./karma.conf.js"
  }
 },
 "defaults": {
  "styleExt": "css",
  "component": {}
 }
}
```

my entire project is on github and the link is: [angular4 and Dot net core shopping cart](https://github.com/santubangalore/shoppingcart)

I have follows this example

[Source example](https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/1206306/Integrating-ASP-Net-Core-and-Angular-project)

But The index page is not opening in the browser, when I run from Visual studio (or by Dotnet run ) . So any help will be appreciated.

My project structure, as you can see,index.html is not copied, and files like main.js, polyfills.js and test.js are copied under src folder.

[image: Project structure]

Comment: it works normally when `"outDir": "dist"` ?

Comment: Hi k11k, have you done this kind of project before? The answer to your question is, no and reason is the file will open in browser, if the file is created in wwwroot only.

Comment: If you look in to your startup.cs `services.AddSpaStaticFiles(configuration =>
            {
                configuration.RootPath = "ClientApp/dist";
            });` changing this path  may help you to work. I didn't try this.

Comment: Sorry, K11k2, that is not going to solve the problem. Actually, when we publish, the wwwroot will be considered for point of start. So how does it help? No, the question is why is index.html not getting copied?

Comment: by changing `"outDir": "wwwroot"` will create wwwroot folder under clientApp  that doesn't mean it generate the build files in dotnet wwroot folder. but don't how you managed to generate `src file generated in that  root.

Comment: Did you run `ng build`?

Comment: When you hover over `outDir` in `.angular-cli.json`, it says "The output directory for build results.". So you would not see anything under your `outDir` folder without running `ng build`

Comment: why do I need to use ng build? Bunyamin Coskuner? Visual studio is supposed to do the job of building angular project and converting to javascript. Where is the mistake in my undestanding? See, I can run the project by ng serve --open --port etc command. But the objective is to run the project from within VS 2017.

Comment: src is my source code in angular instead of clientapp. k11k2, I hope you understand.

Comment: Are you getting 404 not found errors of bundles.js in console ?

Comment: I am getting 404 error, but that is probably because there is no default page, or the default page is not getting copied to wwwroot. as for bundles, I dont know anything.

Comment: My entire project is in github, here : https://github.com/santubangalore/shoppingcart

Comment: Then how does Visual Studio knows you are developing an angular project? Also, how does it know how to build and run your project? Did you configure it somehow?

Comment: [checkThis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45569668/not-able-to-execute-angular-application-locally-after-build/45581902#45581902)

Comment: Ok, Bunyamin Coskuner, I ran the ng build, and it created the files under wwwroot folder. But the browser still shows 404 when I run the application from Vosual studio. So what is missing?

Comment: Now, you have a built application which can be served from any server (independent from angular-cli) At this point, you have to configure your .NET application to serve those files somehow. I'm sorry I don't have any .NET experience, so I cannot help you with that.

Comment: Hi k11k2, this syntax, services.AddSpaStaticFiles, is not valid, it is not compiling under Dot NEt core 2.

Comment: You have to run " ng build --base-href=<ur base url>. for eeg: ng build --base-href=http://localhost:8000/app//             Dont forget to type last "/" otherwise it will show 404

Comment: Hi Sunil, I am unable to understand. My application runs on  http://localhost:6353/, why should I write localhost:8000/app/, what is /app ? I am not clear

Comment: just seen your architecture, any reasons for preparing `src` folder in wwwroot ? and you are not using aspnet core official angular template visit this [ASP NET CORE ANGULAR 5](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/spa/angular?tabs=visual-studio)

Comment: Hi k11k2, I did not create the src folder under wwwroot myself. it got created by itself. But that is corrected now. When I run this command ng build in the command window, the wwwroot folder is re-written. And index.html in copied along with js files. But my problem remains with invoking or displaying the index file in browser. When I run the project thru visual studio, it does not display the index page at all. it shows 404 error. if I addindex.html at the end of the url, then only title is displayed.

Comment: As for using the template, I dont want to use ready made template. That template depends on MVC routing, controllers and razor view. I want to build an SPA without MVC routing. It was easy in MVC 5 and Angular 1. Now to achiieve that much I have to struggle.

Comment: @santubangalore NO, even it didn't provide any Views or HomeController, give a try.

Comment: through `ng build` and `ng serve` your app will run successfully. now you need to search for serving the `index.html` static file on `dotnet run`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the issue. I changed add the below code in startup.cs in configuration method

```
app.Use(async (context, next) =>
  {
    await next();
    if (context.Response.StatusCode == 404 &&
      !context.Request.Path.Value.StartsWith("/api/"))
    {
      context.Request.Path = "/index.html";
      await next();
    }
  });
```

Earlier, it was wwwroot/index.html . Now everything works fine. When I run the project thru dotnet run command all the angular 4 features are available.