# All requests are not found (404) when the application runs on an external server

Tags: angular, request, angular7

My application works fine when served with the `ng serve` command or with the `ng serve --prod` command, but when I build it for production with the `ng build --prod` command and then serve it with the `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/ng-zero` command or with the `live-server --entry-file=dist/index.html` command, any request has a `404` response.

I had a look at different questions and their answers here, but nothing helped. I tried the `HashLocationStrategy` suggestion, I tried the `useHash: true` one too, to no success.

The Http server starting the application:

```
$ http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/ng-zero
Starting up http-server, serving dist/ng-zero
Available on:
  http://127.0.0.1:8080
  http://192.168.0.7:8080
  http://172.19.0.1:8080
Hit CTRL-C to stop the server
[Sat Oct 13 2018 11:19:38 GMT+0200 (CEST)] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
[Sat Oct 13 2018 11:19:38 GMT+0200 (CEST)] "GET /" Error (404): "Not found"
```

It does open a new browser tab on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` but it is blank and the console says:

```
[Sat Oct 13 2018 11:19:38 GMT+0200 (CEST)] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
[Sat Oct 13 2018 11:19:38 GMT+0200 (CEST)] "GET /" Error (404): "Not found"
[Sat Oct 13 2018 11:20:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)] "GET /" "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/69.0.3497.100 Safari/537.36"
[Sat Oct 13 2018 11:20:51 GMT+0200 (CEST)] "GET /" Error (404): "Not found"
```

The Lite server starting the application:

```
$ ll dist/index.html 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 stephane 925 oct.  12 19:35 dist/index.html
[stephane@stephane-ThinkPad-X201 ng-zero (master)]
$ live-server --entry-file=dist/index.html
Serving "/home/stephane/dev/js/projects/angular/ng-zero" at http://127.0.0.1:8080
```

It does open a new browser tab on `http://127.0.0.1:8080/` but it is blank and the console says nothing  at all.

The `index.html` file:

```
$ cat src/index.html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>NgZero</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons" rel="stylesheet">
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.json">
  <meta name="theme-color" content="#1976d2">
</head>
<body class="mat-app-background">
  <app-root></app-root>
  <noscript>Please enable JavaScript to continue using this application.</noscript>
</body>
</html>
```

EDIT:

Here is the folder structure:

```
$ tree 
.
├── app
│   ├── app.component.css
│   ├── app.component.html
│   ├── app.component.spec.ts
│   ├── app.component.ts
│   ├── app-gui.module.ts
│   ├── app.module.ts
│   ├── app-preloading-strategy.ts
│   ├── app-routing.module.ts
│   ├── core
│   │   ├── auth
│   │   │   ├── auth-guard.service.ts
│   │   │   ├── auth.interceptor.ts
│   │   │   ├── auth.module.ts
│   │   │   ├── auth.service.ts
│   │   │   ├── keycloak-client.service.spec.ts
│   │   │   ├── keycloak-client.service.ts
│   │   │   ├── keycloak.interceptor.ts
│   │   │   ├── token.service.spec.ts
│   │   │   └── token.service.ts
│   │   ├── error
│   │   │   ├── error.component.html
│   │   │   ├── error.component.scss
│   │   │   ├── error.component.ts
│   │   │   ├── error-custom-handler.ts
│   │   │   ├── error.module.ts
│   │   │   ├── error-request-interceptor.ts
│   │   │   ├── error-routing.module.ts
│   │   │   ├── error.service.ts
│   │   │   └── index.ts
│   │   ├── login
│   │   │   ├── login.component.css
│   │   │   ├── login.component.html
│   │   │   ├── login.component.spec.ts
│   │   │   ├── login.component.ts
│   │   │   ├── login-dialog.component.html
│   │   │   └── login-dialog.component.ts
│   │   ├── messages
│   │   │   ├── messages.component.css
│   │   │   ├── messages.component.html
│   │   │   ├── messages.component.spec.ts
│   │   │   ├── messages.component.ts
│   │   │   ├── message.service.spec.ts
│   │   │   └── message.service.ts
│   │   └── service
│   │       ├── http.service.ts
│   │       ├── notification.service.ts
│   │       ├── pagination.service.ts
│   │       └── utils.service.ts
│   ├── core.module.ts
│   ├── material.module.ts
│   └── views
│       ├── dashboard
│       │   ├── dashboard.component.css
│       │   ├── dashboard.component.html
│       │   ├── dashboard.component.spec.ts
│       │   └── dashboard.component.ts
│       ├── home
│       │   ├── home.component.css
│       │   ├── home.component.html
│       │   ├── home.component.spec.ts
│       │   ├── home.component.ts
│       │   ├── home.module.ts
│       │   └── home-routing.module.ts
│       └── user
│           ├── search.component.css
│           ├── search.component.html
│           ├── search.component.spec.ts
│           ├── search.component.ts
│           ├── user.component.css
│           ├── user.component.html
│           ├── user.component.spec.ts
│           ├── user.component.ts
│           ├── users.component.css
│           ├── users.component.html
│           ├── users.component.spec.ts
│           ├── users.component.ts
│           ├── user.service.spec.ts
│           ├── user.service.ts
│           └── user.ts
├── assets
│   └── icons
│       ├── icon-128x128.png
│       ├── icon-144x144.png
│       ├── icon-152x152.png
│       ├── icon-192x192.png
│       ├── icon-384x384.png
│       ├── icon-512x512.png
│       ├── icon-72x72.png
│       └── icon-96x96.png
├── environments
│   ├── environment.prod.ts
│   └── environment.ts
├── favicon.ico
├── index.html
├── main.ts
├── manifest.json
├── polyfills.ts
├── styles.css
├── test.ts
├── tsconfig.app.json
├── tsconfig.spec.json
└── typings.d.ts
```

I'm on Angular 7 `^7.0.0-rc.0`

Comment: Is your application not served at all, and you're getting a 404 from the HTTP server? or is your Angular router returning its route not found handler?

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean when you say `not served`.

Comment: I added more information in the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `ng build --prod` command pushes all required files under the `/dist` folder. You just need to copy those files in the server.

If you want to serve the content from the `/dist` folder

1. install `angular-http-server`
2. serve the application as in `angular-http-server --path dist/`

Comment: Why should I copy these files at all ? The server, from where I start it, can find these files.

Comment: NodeJS will not be aware that if it  should run the compiled files ( ready for production ). It will keeping using the development source file. So once the files are generated you can put those files in any web server IIS or Apache.

Comment: Please refer this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389539/how-to-serve-an-angular-2-dist-folder-index-html

Comment: I had followed these instructions `https://angular.io/guide/service-worker-getting-started` where it says `ng build --prod` and `http-server -p 8080 -c-1 dist/<project-name>`

Comment: I can now serve the application fine using the `angular-http-server` as in `angular-http-server --path dist/` but I'd like to have it work under the other servers too.

Comment: Updated the answer as request.

Answer (score 0):

Please check your routing module "RoutesRoutingModule"!! it should look like this

```
environment.useHash = true;

@NgModule({
  imports: [
    RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
      useHash: environment.useHash,
      relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy',
    }),
  ],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
```