# Is node_modules and package.json is need for running dist folder in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, node-modules

in my project, I just deleted every file except the dist folder and server.js but when I `npm start` it saying package.json & node_modules are needed. so my question is I only need the dist folder and server.js, not the other 2 folders is it possible?

I think you guys understand my question if not comment on it I will answer ASAP

package.json
 `{ "name": "ncmsui", "version": "0.0.0", "scripts": { "ng": "ng", "start": "node server.js", "build": "ng build", "test": "ng test", "lint": "ng lint", "e2e": "ng e2e" }, "private": true, "dependencies": { "@angular/animations": "~10.2.0", "@angular/cdk": "^11.2.0", "@angular/common": "~10.2.0", "@angular/compiler": "~10.2.0", "@angular/core": "~10.2.0", "@angular/flex-layout": "^11.0.0-beta.33", "@angular/forms": "~10.2.0", "@angular/material": "^10.2.7", "@angular/platform-browser": "~10.2.0", "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~10.2.0", "@angular/router": "~10.2.0", "ag-grid-angular": "^24.0.0", "ag-grid-community": "^24.0.0", "ag-grid-enterprise": "^24.0.0", "rxjs": "~6.6.0", "tslib": "^2.0.0", "zone.js": "~0.10.2" }, "devDependencies": { "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~0.1002.0", "@angular/cli": "~10.2.0", "@angular/compiler-cli": "~10.2.0", "@types/node": "^12.11.1", "@types/jasmine": "~3.5.0", "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.3", "codelyzer": "^6.0.0", "jasmine-core": "~3.6.0", "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~5.0.0", "karma": "~5.0.0", "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0", "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "~3.0.2", "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0", "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^1.5.0", "protractor": "~7.0.0", "ts-node": "~8.3.0", "tslint": "~6.1.0", "typescript": "~4.0.2" } }`

Comment: please post your package.json file

Comment: @batman567 here it is

Comment: in this config ```npm run start``` will launch ```node server.js```. as answered below - yes - you will then require node_modules and package.json.  contents of your ```dist``` folder is irrelevant

Comment: so the conclusion is that I can't ignore node_modules and package.json. Or is there  is any way

Comment: i remember on AngularJS you could run ```ng serve:dist```. not sure if that came out of the box or whether we built that - but that would run the app from dist folder.  you can look around for something similar in Angular 10

Comment: guys found the perfect solution [there is it](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49236585/14299858)

Comment: cool - well done.  just out of interest - is this an angular or nodejs project? i see signs of both...

Comment: @batman567 it's an angular project. thanks guys !!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At least for Angular apps, angular-http-server seems to be a nicer option.

First install it with your preferred package manager, say

```
npm install angular-http-server -g
```

Answer (score 0):

To run your project local/dev you need node_modules and package.json.

Now just with the dist folder and server.js you can run your project on the could, like Heroku or Aws, because they will provide the correct node environment for your application to run.

Comment: is there is no way to run it locally without node-module and package.json