# Lite-server show blank screen in angular app

Tags: angular, lite-server

I want to use lite-server for testing my angular app in mobile view.
This is my package json:

```
{
  "name": "myapp",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "watch": "ng build --watch --configuration development",
    "test": "ng test",
    "dev": "lite-server"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/cdk": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/common": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/core": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/forms": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/material": "^12.2.1",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "~12.2.0",
    "@angular/router": "~12.2.0",
    "@ngx-translate/core": "^14.0.0",
    "@ngx-translate/http-loader": "^7.0.0",
    "lodash": "^4.17.21",
    "ngx-page-scroll": "^8.0.0",
    "ngx-page-scroll-core": "^8.0.0",
    "random-words": "^1.1.2",
    "rxjs": "^6.6.7",
    "tslib": "^2.3.0",
    "zone.js": "~0.11.4"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular-devkit/build-angular": "~12.2.1",
    "@angular/cli": "^12.2.13",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "~12.2.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~3.8.0",
    "@types/node": "^12.11.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~3.8.0",
    "karma": "^6.3.17",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~3.1.0",
    "karma-coverage": "~2.0.3",
    "karma-jasmine": "~4.0.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "~1.7.0",
    "lite-server": "^2.6.1",
    "typescript": "~4.3.5"
  }
}
```

When I run my app use command `npm run dev` I see only blank screen with my title.
I already have tryed to build app first then run in folder `dist`, but it didn't help, I also see blank screen without any errors in console.

Answer (score 0):

As you can see [here](https://angular.io/guide/deployment):

When you have installed lite-server, you have to run this command:

```
lite-server --baseDir="dist/project-name"
```

Where **project-name** is, at its name says, your project name, which is the name of your main folder.

You can also try **http-server**, you can see another question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43389539/how-to-serve-an-angular-2-dist-folder-index-html), and the docu from [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular-http-server).

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it doesn't help, I also see blank screen(

Comment: Blank screen when doing ng build and then lite-server --baseDir="dist/project-name" ?

Comment: Yes, I also try to do it in two terminals in first ng build --watch, in second lite-server --baseDir="dist/my-app"

Comment: I edited my answer, give it a try please

Comment: It doesn't help. I try to use angular-http-server, which also doesn't help. Also I try to create new default angular project and I also see blank screen. What realy help, to use command http-server in dist folder.